# Recursive function that returns a Vec

Tags: recursion, rust, flatten

I continue to struggle with the concept of recursion.  I have a function that takes a `u64` and returns a `Vec<u64>` of factors of that integer.  I would like to recursively call this function on each item in the `Vec`, returning a flattened `Vec` until the function returns `Vec<self>` for each item, i.e., each item is prime.

```
fn prime_factors(x: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let factors = factoring_method(x);
    factors.iter().flat_map(|&i| factoring_method(i)).collect()
}
```

([The complete code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=44be4e411fea0db7486c3a2f723b3590&version=stable))

This returns only the `Vec` of factors of the final iteration and also has no conditional that allows it to keep going until items are all prime.

The `factoring_method` is a congruence of squares that I'm pretty happy with.  I'm certain there's lots of room for optimization, but I'm hoping to get a working version complete before refactoring.  I think the recursion should in the `congruence_of_squares` — calling itself upon each member of the `Vec` it returns, but I'm not sure how to frame the conditional to keep it from doing so infinitely.

Comment: Actually, it's hard to answer without that `factoring_method`. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Are `factoring_method` and `prime_factors` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: @sellibitze -- no the factoring method is separate and you have hit upon the same conceptual problem Shepmaster pointed out.  I apologize for not updating the question with the code requested by E_net4.  Been sick for a few days.  I'll try to update this evening to clarify.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct that `congruence_of_squares(9)` returns `[1, 9]`.

Comment: @Shepmaster why not?  Squares less than or equal to 9 are only 4 and 9.  4 is not a factor of 9, so it should return 9 and its complementary factor 1.

Comment: I should not have used "correct" (I actually don't understand congruence of squares or it's purpose), it would have been better for me to say "useful". If it returns `[1, 9]`, then there's no forward progress possible for the algorithm; it will infinitely try to compute the factors of `9`, which has the factor `9`, which requires the factors of `9`, etc.

Comment: Right.  Congruence of squares is only useful, AFAIK, for factoring very large numbers.  But I don't claim to fully grok it myself.  It's a bit frustrating b/c the textbook examples all use large semiprimes, so only one iteration is needed to find the prime factors.  I'm not sure if that implies it's main utility is in large semiprimes or not.

Answer (score 2):

Useful recursion requires two things:

1. That a function call itself, either directly or indirectly.
2. That there be some terminating case.

One definition of the prime factorization of a number is:

- if the number is prime, that is the only prime factor
- otherwise, combine the prime factors of a pair of factors of the number

From that, we can identify a termination condition ("if it's prime") and the recursive call ("prime factors of factors").

Note that we haven't written any code yet — everything to this point is conceptual.

We can then transcribe the idea to Rust:

```
fn prime_factors(x: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    if is_prime(x) {
        vec![x]
    } else {
        factors(x).into_iter().flat_map(prime_factors).collect()
    }
}
```

Interesting pieces here:

- We use `into_iter` to avoid the need to dereference the iterated value.
- We can pass the function name directly as the closure because the types align.

Some (inefficient) helper functions round out the implementation:

```
fn is_prime(x: u64) -> bool {
    !(2..x).any(|i| x % i == 0)
}

fn factors(x: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    match (2..x).filter(|i| x % i == 0).next() {
        Some(v) => vec![v, x / v],
        None => vec![],
    }
}
```